# Help with a volume integral.

Tags: integration

[This is my fourth attempt...not sure if I'm doing something wrong here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SITBM.jpg)Find the volume of the solid bounded below by the rectangle RR: $1≤y≤e$, $1≤x≤2,$ in the $xy$-plane and above by the graph of $z=f(x,y)=x\ln(xy)$.

This problem requires double integration, which is fine, but it requires some complicated integration by parts involving two variables. I have done this problem 3 times and something keeps messing up... Any help apprecitated

Comment: show us what you tried and well help you spot the error

Answer (score 1):

Between the first and second line of your working you had
$$\int_{1}^{e}\ln(xy)dy=\big[xy\ln(xy)-xy\big]_{1}^{e}$$
This is wrong. This integral is
$$\int_{1}^{e}\ln(xy)dy=\int_{1}^{e}\ln x+\ln y\ dy=\big[y\ln x+y\ln y-y\big]_{1}^{e}=(e-1)\ln x+1.$$